# Session affinity for HTTP load balancing on Google Cloud

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Google Cloud has sticky sessions for network load balancing, but how to enable stickiness for *HTTP* load balancing. Just can not find...

Comment: The feature to have sticky session for HTTP load balancer is currently not available. As such, you can go ahead and file a feature request through this link (https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, unfortunately session affinity is only available for *Network* load balancing. Just left a feature request at: https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=240&thanks=240&ts=1442238732.

Please, vote!

Comment: Aren't you using nginx until these things come out of alpha/beta?

Answer (score 4):

Now the feature of sticky session is extended to Google Cloud HTTP(S) Load balancer. We can have session affinity either by [Client IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-service#client_ip_affinity) or [Client Cookie](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-service#generated_cookie_affinity).
For more information please refer this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#session_affinity).

Answer (score 3):

This feature has been released, but is currently in **alpha** phase.

[Client IP affinity](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-service#client_ip_affinity)

Note: Generated cookie affinity seems like a much better option. Solves two of the issues related to IP affinity, as mentioned in the link.

Comment: Now upgraded to beta.